# Probability in lottery

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A lottery ticket consists of a 7-digit number where each of the digits are one of the numbers $0,1,\dots ,9$. The number of **correct** digits are the number of digits **from right to left**. Eg. if the correct number is: 1234567 and one's ticket has 1234569, one has no correct digits.

**Questions:**

1. **Find the probability of having 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 0 correct digits.**

**My answer:**

$E=\{(e_1,\dots,e_7)\ | e_i\in \{0,\dots,9\} \}$

$\#E=10^7$.

$\#A_1=1\cdot 9\cdot 10^5$

$P(A_1)=\frac{9\cdot 10^5}{10^7}$

and so on for $A_2,\dots,A_7$ and $A_0$.

**2. What is the probability of having at least 4 correct digits?**

**My answer:**

Call this event $B$.
$P(B)=P(A_4)+P(A_5)+P(A_6)+P(A_7)=\frac{9\cdot 10^2}{10^7}+\frac{9\cdot 10}{10^7}+\frac{9}{10^7}+\frac{1}{10^7}=\frac{1}{10^4}$

Now Assume one plays the lottery once a week for three weeks.

**3. What is the probability of having at least 4 correct digits in precisely one lottery in the three weeks?**

HELP!

4. **What is the probability of having at least 4 correct digits in at least one lottery in the three weeks?**

HELP!

Comment: In your third statement, there are six numbers that are right in digits and position and you call it "has no correct digits". and then you are asking the prob to find the 4 correct digits and so on, Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: 3. and 4. deal with binomial distribution with parameters $n=3$ and $p=$ the probability of at least $4$ correct digits. So if you know $p$ then you can solve it.

Comment: I get it right to left, so, if the number is 1234469 and the lottery is 3468569, you would say there are 2 correct digits?

Comment: @satishramanathan yes

Comment: @satishramanathan Edited now. I had called written the wrong indexes one the A's.

Comment: The answer for Problem 2 is fine, but there are typos in the subscripts of the $A_i$. By the way, the $\frac{1}{10^4}$ can be obtained without addition.

Comment: you are right, it looks right now numbers are right now, do you still need help with Part III and Part IV after @drhab's comment

Comment: @satishramanathan yes, I still need help with 3 and 4.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How?

Comment: The probability of at least $4$ correct digits is the probability the first four (from the right) are right. This is $\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n = 3

p = Part II answer

1-p = 1 - part II answer

Part III, $$P(n = 1) = {3\choose1}p(1-p)^2$$

Part IV, $$P(n>=1) = 1-{3\choose0} (1-p)^3$$

Comment: Isn't there missing a $p$ in your part IV answer?

Comment: It should have been $p^0$ which is anyway 1 and that is the reason why I omitted.  Ideally, it is $1-{3\choose0}p^0(1-p)^3$.  Hope you get it

Comment: Also, how can I see from the formula of the binomial coefficient that $(3,0)$ is 1? Is makes sense conceptually but I can't see it from the formula: $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: Why can't you? Substitute the value of n and k with n being 3 and k being 0 So $ \frac{3!}{0!3!} = 1$ because 0! = 1

Comment: I get that the probability that I get at least 4 correct at least one time in the three weeks is bigger that the probability of getting at least 4 correct precisely one time in the three weeks. Shouldn't I get the reverse?

Comment: You are right, the meaning of getting atleast 4 correct atleast one time includes one time, two times, three times.  Its probability should be higher than getting it exactly one time.  It should not be the reverse.